# How to use Apache Camel platform-http with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, apache-camel

In my opinion the Apache Camel documentation does not provide sophisticated information on how to use Apache Camel platform-http together with Spring Boot.

For example, with this route

```
 from("platform-http:/test?httpMethodRestrict=POST")
     .to("log:foo");
```

I'm running into

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PlatformHttpEngine is neither set on this endpoint neither found in Camel Registry or FactoryFinder.

How to specify such an PlatformHttpEngine is nowhere documented here and it reads as if it is working out of the box

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/platform-http-component.html

Comment: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/spring-summary.html ?

Comment: @K.Nicholas Thanks, maybe I'm blind but I don't see anything that would help me there

Answer (score 0):

I think this is confusing as well, and my first attempt was using `platform-http` as well.

Then I found there is a `rest` component: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/rest-component.html

To have a complete setup of REST component on Camel, please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084154/19589355